# How to get accurate timing interval by using plotly dash?

Tags: python, plotly, timing, plotly-dash

I would like to create a stopwatch using python plotly dash and the following is my code. Here I use the element `dcc.Interval` to update timing information every one second, but unfortunately, I found that it is not accurate when I used my iPhone built-in stopwatch to test its accuracy. Any suggestion on how how to correct my code? Thanks :)

```
# import modules
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output


# define functions
def sec_transform(i):
    m, s = divmod(i, 60)
    msg = '%02i:%02i' % (m, s)
    return msg


# dashboard layout
app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([

    # display time elapsed
    html.H1(id='live-update-text'),

    # for live updating
    dcc.Interval(
        id='interval-component',
        interval=1000,  # 1000 milliseconds
        n_intervals=0
    )
])


# call back function
@app.callback(Output('live-update-text', 'children'),
              [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')])
def update_layout(n):
    msg = sec_transform(n)
    return msg


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: There may be an inherent flaw in using a web app to measure time accurately. The latency, network requests, etc., are all going to work against this.

Comment: @coralvanda Got it! Thank you for your reply. I may change to use matplotlib, which allows me to do it without internet connection.